# Should I use 2' x 2' tiles for a galley kitchen?

Tags: kitchens, tile

I am redoing my kitchen and I'm considering using a large tile size. Are 2 foot by 2 foot tiles difficult to work with? Will I run into problems with size limitations of the tools I'm using and layout difficulties? I'll be working in my galley kitchen which is about 6 feet by 10 feet. I thought the bigger tiles would result in the least amount of grout lines, which is something which appeals to me.

Are there other factors such as tile material that I should consider as well? Are some types of tile easier to maintain than others?

Comment: This is largely an aesthetic question ,as you point out.  It's not great for this site.

Comment: It will be difficult to find a snap cutter large enough to cut the diagonals. With a wet saw, it doesn't make much difference how big the tiles are.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to have a solid surface for large tiles.  The actual tiling is not the hard part.  You need to make sure you have a very very flat concrete or backer board subfloor.

As for installing the tiles the only thing "harder" is that you will have to back butter your tiles.  Also if you mess up a cut bad it costs you more.

The flip side is if your subfloor is set up right you can have a really nice looking kitchen floor.  The big tiles do look nicer and clean easier.  Also if you start in the right spot all/most of your cut edges can be hidden easier.